# Django Web application using R analysis

Tags: r, django, rpy2

I have done some data analysis on R, Now I am willing to display the results & visualizations on Django Web application How should I do it.?

1) Save results in database and make a Django app independently while display results by fetching from database.

2) I am not sure but what what purpose rpy2 does here? Should I call my R function in python and make a Django app (pardon if this point doesn't make sense)

Answer (score 0):

From experience, using `Rpy2` is a bit of a mess. I would go with option 1 if you have time. If you're in a rush, you can use `Rpy2`, both techniques will work but the first one is less dirty probably.

You might want to take a look at some `R` to build web applications like [this one](https://shiny.rstudio.com/)?